# Aliasing in Bulk Collect giving error of unimplemented feature

Tags: plsql

The problem statement: The user would specify a name based on which I have to pull names of two tables from a table and then extract values from those tables.I have created a pl/sql procedure for that and since the select query can return n number of rows I'm using Bulk Collect. I have created and object based on the fields I want to extract. Now the problem is that the columns are common in both the tables, so if I don't use alias I get ambiguous column error and if I use that I get the error of unimplemented feature.

here's my code:

```
create or replace type recon_obj_vib 
is object (RECON_TABLE_KEY NUMBER(19)
,RECON_CHGLOGATTR_IDXLST  VARCHAR2(1000 CHAR));

create or replace type recon_tab_vib
is table of recon_obj_vib;

create or replace PROCEDURE noMatchReport_proc(tableDesc IN VARCHAR2)
IS
l_recon_tab_vib recon_tab_vib := recon_tab_vib();
n Integer :=0;
out varchar2(2000);
tableName1  varchar2(25);
tableName2 varchar2(25);
tableDesc_without_space varchar2(25);
tableDesc_ra varchar2(25);

BEGIN
 tableDesc_without_space:=Regexp_Replace(tableDesc,'\s');
 tableDesc_ra:=UPPER('RA_' || tableDesc_without_space || ' %');
 out:= 'Select recon_table_name from recon_tables where recon_table_desc = (:value) and rownum=1 and RECON_TABLE_name like (:userName)';
 execute immediate out into tableName1 USING tableDesc,tableDesc_ra;
 out:= 'Select recon_table_name from recon_tables where recon_table_desc = (:value) and rownum=1 and RECON_TABLE_name  not like (:userName)';
  execute immediate out into tableName2 USING tableDesc,tableDesc_ra;
  out:='Select a.RECON_TABLE_KEY,a.RECON_CHGLOGATTR_IDXLST BULK COLLECT INTO  l_recon_tab_vib from ' || tableName1  || ' a , ' || tableName2 ||  ' b where a.RE_KEY = b.RE_KEY and rownum=1';
  execute immediate out into l_recon_tab_vib;
  FOR i IN 1..l_recon_tab_vib.COUNT 
   LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('RECON_TABLE_KEY '||     l_recon_tab_vib(i).RECON_TABLE_KEY ||' RECON_CHGLOGATTR_IDXLST ' || l_recon_tab_vib(i).RECON_CHGLOGATTR_IDXLST );
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

This part:

```
out:='Select a.RECON_TABLE_KEY,a.RECON_CHGLOGATTR_IDXLST BULK COLLECT INTO   l_recon_tab_vib from ' || tableName1  || ' a , ' || tableName2 ||  ' b where a.RE_KEY = b.RE_KEY and rownum=1';
execute immediate out into l_recon_tab_vib;
```

Should be:

```
out:='Select a.RECON_TABLE_KEY,a.RECON_CHGLOGATTR_IDXLST from ' 
     || tableName1  || ' a , ' || tableName2
     ||  ' b where a.RE_KEY = b.RE_KEY and rownum=1';
execute immediate bulk collect into l_recon_tab_vib;
```

i.e. the `BULK COLLECT INTO` clause is part of the calling PL/SQL not part of the dynamic SQL.